# fetchRequest on restkit version 0.20 - No Known Class Method

Tags: ios, restkit, nsfetchrequest

I am moving from RestKit 0.10 to 0.20 on one of my application. I reviewed the page at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0, but didn't see this issue.

- edit 2013-02-09 Added mapping code and loadObjectData method *

RestKit was added via CocoaPods.

This was working in RK 0.10, then compiled in RK 0.20. This fragment does:

1. Create the fetchRequest
2. Add a predicate
3. Add a sort
4. Fetch the array of repeaters

I have the following imports, in order:

```
// RestKit
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import <RestKit/CoreData.h>

// Core Data
#import "Repeaters.h"
```

Code snippet:

```
    NSArray *sortDescriptors;
*1  NSFetchRequest *sortedRequest = [Repeaters fetchRequest]; // RestKit 0.10
    // NSFetchRequest *sortedRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Repeaters"]; // RestKit 0.20?

    // Predicate Filter by Grouping
    NSString *predicateString = @"";

    if ([appDelegate getIncludeIrlpPreference]) {
        predicateString =  [predicateString stringByAppendingFormat:@"(grouping LIKE 'irlp')"];
    }

    if ([appDelegate getIncludeWsiPreference]) {
        if([predicateString length] > 0) predicateString = [predicateString stringByAppendingFormat:@" OR "];
        predicateString =  [predicateString stringByAppendingFormat:@"(grouping LIKE 'winsystem')"];
    }

    // Distance Sort
    if([selectedSegmentString isEqualToString:kRepeaterSortDistance]) {

        // Sort by distance
        NSSortDescriptor * sortBydistance = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
        sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortBydistance, nil ];

    }

    // Add the Sort to the fetch request
    [sortedRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Add the Predicate to the fetch request
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
    [sortedRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // Fetch the data - filtered and sorted
*2  self.repeaters = [Repeaters objectsWithFetchRequest:sortedRequest]; // RestKit 0.10
```

Mapping code for Repeaters class:

```
 RKManagedObjectMapping *repeatersMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:kEntityRepeaters inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"callSign" toAttribute:@"callSign"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"country" toAttribute:@"country"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"freqOffsetPl" toAttribute:@"freqOffsetPl"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"grouping" toAttribute:@"grouping"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"latitudeDefault" toAttribute:@"latitudeDefault"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"longitudeDefault" toAttribute:@"longitudeDefault"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"locationElevation" toAttribute:@"locationElevation"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"node" toAttribute:@"node"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"notes" toAttribute:@"notes"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"repeaterId" toAttribute:@"repeaterId"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"serviceArea" toAttribute:@"serviceArea"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"serviceState" toAttribute:@"serviceState"];
 [repeatersMapping mapKeyPath:@"url" toAttribute:@"url"];
 repeatersMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = kEntityRepeaterKey;
 [wsiObjectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:repeatersMapping withRootKeyPath:@"winSystem.winSystemRepeaters.winSystemRepeater"];
```

loadObjectData method:

```
- (void)loadObjectData {

        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:kWinSystemInfoXml delegate:self];
}
```

Xcode errors:

---

*1 RepeatersTableViewController.m:116:37: No known class method for selector 'fetchRequest'

*2 RepeatersTableViewController.m:170:22: No known class method for selector 'objectsWithFetchRequest:'

---

It is like the core data bits were not added to the Repeaters class.

Is there another document for v0.10 to v0.20 conversion that would help me to see more of the changes?

Comment: What about the request? Can you perhaps provide more code because it seems that there is something missing. Do you use object mapping? Add this to your answer as well.

Comment: `sortedRequest` is the request, and  `[Repeaters objectsWithFetchRequest:sortedRequest];` call performs the fetch using that request. Managed Object Mapping code has been added to the question.

Comment: Okay, just reviewed your question and saw that your actually trying to run a RestKit v.10 configuration with v.20 - that wouldn't work caused by the fact that the process has been rewritten in v.20. Check out the link nous posted and edit your methods to get things working again!

Comment: Yep, recoding to match the new scheme. Too bad, it was working so nice.

Answer (score 1):

Without reviewing your question in detail, https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping has answered many of my restkit .20 questions.

Comment: Thank you. I'll start there now,